# Semi-random binder transaction errors

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting a TransactionTooLargeException at (what seem to be) random points throughout my application as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:498)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:313)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2000)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:128)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1165)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472): Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:516)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:488)
E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    ... 17 more
```

I mainly get this exception thrown at me when i try to display a dialog or manually open an action bar menu, but it seems to be really picky about when it happens: I can use the application for a couple minutes without issues and it suddenly happens, but i've also experienced it right away as soon as i open my application.

Any ideas are deeply welcomed.

EDIT:
Similar questions always mention a service, which i do have. I have an [authenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) service that exchanges really light payloads consisting mostly of an intent and auth credentials. Shouldn't be too bad on the transaction buffer but i'd have to profile that somehow.

Comment: It normally happens when you pass a huge data via intent. If I'm not wrong, it has a 1 MB limit. See if you have something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with no service involved, just passing large object graphs to another activity via Intent. Maybe a [blog post](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/yet-another-post-on-serializable-vs-parcelable-1e829e98472) I just wrote can help you understand the issue.

Comment: Sorry i didn't update this question; this was related to the Xamarin profiler being enabled, turning it off fixed all of my problems. That's still a pretty good article, good job.